# How do I broadcast a Bluetooth signal while in the foreground and background in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbperipheralmanager

How do I broadcast a bluetooth signal in Swift? My goal is to then discover this device with another device. I have tried using the `CBPeripheralManager.startAdvertising` function but `CBPeripheralManager.isAdvertising` always returns false.

Also how does broadcasting in the background work? Is it any different than broadcasting in the foreground? The Core Bluetooth Programming Guide says that you should assign your manager a `restoration identifier` but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code you have attempted.